# why does my OLED display with the SH1106 driver have a horizontal offset?

Tags: i2c, stm32f4, stm32cubeide

I have a Nucleo F401RE and want to use my display with it. I have those two I2C functions:

```c
void sh1106_sendCMD(uint8_t cmd)
{
    uint8_t reg_cmd[2];
    reg_cmd[0] = 0x00;
    reg_cmd[1] = cmd;
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, OLED_I2C_ADDRESS, reg_cmd, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

void sh1106_sendData(uint8_t data)
{
    uint8_t reg_data[2];
    reg_data[0] = 0x40;     // write data
    reg_data[1] = data;
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, OLED_I2C_ADDRESS, reg_data, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}
```

Then I have an init function to initialize the Display

```c
void sh1106_init(void)
{
  // Initialize the display
  sh1106_sendCMD(0xAE); // Set display off
  sh1106_sendCMD(0xD5); // Set display clock divide ratio/oscillator frequency
  sh1106_sendCMD(0x80); // Set display clock divide ratio/oscillator frequency
  sh1106_sendCMD(0xA8); // Set multiplex ratio
  sh1106_sendCMD(0x3F); // 1/64 duty
  sh1106_sendCMD(0xD3); // Set display offset
  sh1106_sendCMD(0x00); // No offset
  sh1106_sendCMD(0x40); // Set start line address
  sh1106_sendCMD(0xA1); // Set segment re-map
  sh1106_sendCMD(0xC8); // Set COM output scan direction
  sh1106_sendCMD(0xDA); // Set COM pins hardware configuration
  sh1106_sendCMD(0x12);
  sh1106_sendCMD(0x81); // Set contrast control register
  sh1106_sendCMD(0xFF); // Maximum contrast
  sh1106_sendCMD(0xA4); // Set display to RAM
  sh1106_sendCMD(0xA6); // Set normal display
  sh1106_sendCMD(0xD9); // Set pre-charge period
  sh1106_sendCMD(0xF1);
  sh1106_sendCMD(0xDB); // Set VCOMH deselect level
  sh1106_sendCMD(0x40);
  sh1106_sendCMD(0x8D); // Set charge pump enable/disable
  sh1106_sendCMD(0x14); // Enable charge pump
  sh1106_sendCMD(0xAF); // Set display on
}
```

When I then try to set the pixel (x=0, y=0), nothing happens, but when I set the pixel (x=2, y=0) the pixel (x=0, y=0) turns on. Somehow I have a horizontal offset of -2.

I set the pixel like this:

```c
sh1106_sendCMD(0xB0 | 0); // Set the page address
sh1106_sendCMD(0x02); // Set the lower column address
sh1106_sendCMD(0x10); // Set the higher column address
sh1106_sendData(0x01);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a 128 by 64 pixel display. The SH1106 however supports up to 132 by 64 pixel. So there are 4 unused pixel columns.

The easiest solution is to always add 2 to all x-coordinates.

If you feel more adventurous, you can configure the SH1106 accordingly. Given the limited information about your display, I can only guess. I could be:

```
sh1106_sendCMD(0x42);
```

replacing:

```
sh1106_sendCMD(0x40);
```

See the SH1106 datasheet for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
// if using SH1106 and ss_oled-library change 2 lines in ss_oled.h:
// OLED type for init function
enum {
OLED_128x128 = -1,// this was set to 1 but should be -1
OLED_128x32,
OLED_128x64,
OLED_132x64 = 1,
OLED_64x32,
OLED_96x16,
OLED_72x40
};
```